# Typed Dataset and Multiple Transactions

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I am using Typed Dataset (.xsd) for accessing and updating my database.
I have two table adapters for updating records in two different tables.

I am not able to find out a way to perform two updates in single transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TransactionScope`:

```
            using (var ts = new TransactionScope())
            {
                // Perform updates using different table adapters
                using (var ta1 = new tbl1TableAdapter())
                using (var ta2 = new tbl2TableAdapter())
                {
                    ta1.Update(yourDataSet.tbl1);
                    ta2.Update(yourDataSet.tbl2);
                }

                ts.Complete();
                yourDataSet.AcceptChanges();
            }
```

You can read about `TransactionScope` class [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx)